# How to set gdb-multiarch to support PowerPC architecture?

Tags: gdb

The command `set arch <arch, e.g. arm, mips>` is used to set gdb-multiarch to support a specific architecture. When specify `set arch arm`, it responses `The target architecture is assumed to be arm.` While specify `set arch powerpc`, it responses `Ambiguous item "powerpc".`

What is the proper way to set gdb-multiarch to support PowerPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While specify set arch powerpc, it responses Ambiguous item "powerpc".

Type `(gdb) set arch`. GDB will respond with a list of available architectures. In my build, I see:

```
... powerpc:common64, powerpc:common, powerpc:603, powerpc:EC603e, powerpc:604,
powerpc:403, powerpc:601, powerpc:620, powerpc:630, powerpc:a35, powerpc:rs64ii,
powerpc:rs64iii, powerpc:7400, powerpc:e500, powerpc:e500mc, powerpc:e500mc64,
powerpc:MPC8XX, powerpc:750, powerpc:titan, powerpc:vle, powerpc:e5500,
powerpc:e6500, ...
```

You *probably* want `powerpc:common64` or `powerpc:common`.